# how to send cookie value as input to rest service in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I need to implement functionality for sending cookie value as a input value to the rest based web service in objective-c. can you please help me on this.

i use below code to storage cookie value

```
  NSMutableDictionary *cookieProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  [cookieProperties setObject:@"SampleCookie" forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
  [cookieProperties setObject:@"123456" forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];
  [cookieProperties setObject:@"www.abcdef.com" forKey:NSHTTPCookieDomain];

  NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cookieProperties];
  [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
```